# How to take particular ascendant of an child using jquery.?

Tags: jquery

Hai i am having the following html list.

```
<ol id="queryList">
  <li id="queryLi1">
     <span class="contentParent">First Level</span>
      <ul class="content">
        <li id="innerList594" class="content">
             Second Level
              <ul class="content">
                    <li>
                        Third Level
                        <textarea id="text1" cols="3" style="width: 250px"></textarea>
                        <input id="button1" type="button"  value="Save" >
                   </li>
             </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="queryLi2">
      <span class="contentParent">First Level</span>
      <ul class="content">
        <li id="innerList525" class="content">
              Second Level
              <ul class="content">
                    <li>
                        Third Level
                        <textarea id="text2" cols="3" style="width: 250px"></textarea>
                        <input id="button2" type="button" value="Save">
                   </li>
             </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
      .
      .
      .(etc.,)
```

In this list when i click on `Save button1` i want to take its ascendant `<li id="queryLi1"><span class="contentParent">`
element. Same as for all the list items ..For example if i click `Save button2` i want to take `<li id="queryLi2"><span class="contentParent">`..

I tried like this

```
 var ascende = $(this).closest('.contentParent');
```

but i didnt get it.. Can any one help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.contentParent` is not a direct relative, you need to find the closest common parent and then traverse from there:

```
var ascende = $(this).closest('#queryLi1').find('.contentParent');
```

If you need to do this on many items, add a class name to the outer most `LI` and use a class selector instead of `#queryLi1`.

Alternatively, find a sibling and then traverse, f.ex:

```
var ascende = $(this).parents('ul').slice(-1).prev();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by getting a list of parents with the class `content` and taking the last one, then check the siblings of that for a span with the class `contentParent`. This does assume that there are no more `ul` elements with a class of `content` further up the dom.

```
var span = $(this)
        .parents('ul.content')
        .last()
        .siblings('span.contentParent');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UQhte/

Answer (score -1):

You can use the .parents() jquery method.

```
$(this).parents('.contentParent');
```

This will retrieve the first found ancestor. Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/HLATf/3/

Comment: If you are going to make a jsfiddle to show that your answer is right, you might want to actually use the html posted in the question. Also, the answer is wrong as the contentParent span is not a parent of the button in the example.